# Autohotkey Prevent GUI from closing after pressing Button

Tags: autohotkey, gui

The GUI closes every time I press the "Kitch" button. What I did temporarily is to put "Gui, Show" in order to make the button reappear again.

```
Gui, Add, Button, x2 y0 w110 h60 , Kitch
Gui, Show, x127 y87 h64 w120, NoActivate
return

ButtonKitch:
Gui, Submit
Send {HOME}+{END}The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.{RETURN}
Gui, Show
return
```

Comment: Try `Gui, Submit, NoHide`

Answer (score 0):

Solved: +E0x08000000
Added on the top of GUI.

Comment: Can you describe what this does, or how you went about it? Putting text without any explanation into something that runs can be hazardous, and seen as dangerous to those who don't understand what it does. As well, you should merge your accounts (assuming you posted the question), so you can take charge and let us know of any other solutions you may find.